# Noscript elements not displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a AJAX/Javascript intensive webpage and is trying to create a static version of the site using `<noscript>` tags.

**Problem:** The elements within the `<noscript>` tags do not show up, but instead what's on the screen is what's left of the (non-functioning) interface for the original AJAX/JS site. It appears that the contents of `<noscript>` are being hidden under the original interface's divs.

How can I hide everything outside of the `<noscript>` section, and only show the contents of `<noscript>`?

**HTML Structure**

```
<body>
    <div id="user_interface"></div>
    <div id="javascript_portion"></div>
    <noscript>
        <p>Some static content</p>
    </noscript>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can be done in two steps:

1) set css for `#user_interface` and `#javascript_portion` to `display:none`

2) set `display` to `block` for same selectors somewhere in JS

Comment: Or just put the `display:none` css in its own stylesheet, and wrap that stylesheet in `<noscript>` tags as well. That way no JS is needed to display the elements.

Answer (score 0):

You could add display:none using CSS to your javascript_portion div. And then remove it using Javascript. That way the Javascript part will only show if javascript is working.

Answer (score 0):

How about writing the other content with Javascript, like:

```
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.write('<div id="user_interface"></div>');
    document.write('<div id="javascript_portion"></div>');
  </script>
  <noscript>
    <p>Some static content</p>
  </noscript>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `noscript` tag is like an else section; as in if you have script, do xxx else do the stuff in the noscript tag.

Try something like this (I use jquery below):

```
<body>
  <div id="withScriptBody" style="display:none">
    ... all stuff that requires java script here.
  </div>
  <noscript>
    ... all noscript stuff here
  </noscript>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function()
      {
        $("#withScriptBody").css("display", "block");
      });
  </script>
</body>
```